# User info singleton with userdefaults returns nil

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to store user info into userDefaults and assign those to singleton. I am saving the info after successful API call. I know for sure that it saves all those values. But for some reason the singleton returns nil.

This is my User class:

```
class User {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var email: String
    var profile_image_url: String
    var token: String

    init(id: Int, name: String, email: String, profile_image_url: String, token: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.profile_image_url = profile_image_url
        self.token = token
    }

    init?(dict: [String: JSON]) {
        guard let id = dict["id"]?.intValue,
            let name = dict["name"]?.stringValue,
            let email = dict["email"]?.stringValue,
            let profile_image_url = dict["profile_image_url"]?.stringValue,
            let token = dict["token"]?.stringValue
            else{ return nil }

        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.profile_image_url = profile_image_url
        self.token = token

    }

    class var sharedInstance: User {
        struct Singleton {
            static var instance : User = {
                let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                let keychain = KeychainSwift()
                let user = User(
                    id: userDefaults.integer(forKey: "user_id"),
                    name: userDefaults.string(forKey: "name")!,
                    email: userDefaults.string(forKey: "email")!,
                    profile_image_url: userDefaults.string(forKey: "profile_image_url")!,
                    token: keychain.get("token")!
                )
                return user
            }()
        }

        return Singleton.instance
    }
}
```

And this is how I save values after API call:

```
class func saveUserData(user_id: Int, name: String, email: String, profile_image_url: String, token:String) {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let keychain = KeychainSwift()
        keychain.clear()
        userDefaults.set(user_id, forKey: "user_id")
        userDefaults.set(name, forKey: "name")
        userDefaults.set(email, forKey: "email")
        userDefaults.set(profile_image_url, forKey: "profile_image_url")

        keychain.set(token, forKey: "token")

    }
```

What I am doing wrong, is it even right approach?

Comment: Why are you inheriting from NSObject? Why is your sharedInstance a property of your User?

Comment: @LeoDabus Accidentally, but this shouldn't affect it, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I would start making your User a struct. Discard Swifty JSON. Use Codable. Move your singleton out of your User. Make it a class and change your instance property to static constant. So I can't really understand just by looking at it the whole picture.

Comment: I have never used KeychainSwift either and To save your User into UserDefaults you would need to make it NSCoding compliant

Comment: You should also make all your properties constants

Comment: Where is the code that saves the values?

Comment: @dan I edited with the function.

Comment: Where is the code that calls that function?

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp if you are planing to make it  NSCoding compliant you will need to inherit from NSObject

Comment: What Swift version are you using?

Comment: @dan I think it is not necessary since I know for fact that it saves those values. I've tested it and also, I am using Swift 4.

Comment: So make it a struct and Codable

Comment: So looks like you will only have to save a single User. Is it right?

Comment: @LeoDabus Only single user per device yes.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp don't use snake_case for your properties. Use camelCase

Comment: I'm no JSON coder, but if the issue is with `token: keychain.get("token")!` returning nil, could you *break it out* - even if to fix the underlying issue - into a separate statement? Do a `set` and `get`? It might shine a light on the issue.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp check my post

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp note that you are not restricted to a single user into your user defaults anymore. You can save as many users as needed.

Comment: If you need to use custom keys from your api show me the keys I can show you how to implement it.

Comment: I guess the only one would be profile_image_url. If you can't change your api to profileImageUrl let me know

Comment: Also you could just change the property name back to  profile_image_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned, if you are coding in Swift 4 you should take advantage of the Codable protocol. Make your user a struct that conforms to Codable. You can provide your User struct custom coding keys if needed (not required). Add a method to save your user data to user defaults and create a fallible initializer to read your user data from it:

---

```
struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let email: String
    let profileImageUrl: String
    let token: String
    init(id: Int, name: String, email: String, profileImageUrl: String, token: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl
        self.token = token
    }

    func saveToDefaults() -> Bool {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        do {
            let json = try encoder.encode(self)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(json, forKey: "User\(id)Key")
            return true
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return false
        }
    }
    init?(data: Data) {
        do {
            self = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    init?(id: Int) {
        guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "User\(id)Key") else { return nil }
        self.init(data: data)
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing

```
let user = User(id: 1, name: "a name", email: "name@email.com", profileImageUrl: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg", token: "anyTokenString")

if user.saveToDefaults() {
    print("success")
    if let user = User(id: 1) {
        print(user.id)
        print(user.name)
        print(user.email)
        print(user.profileImageUrl)
        print(user.token)
    } else {
        print("there is no user with id 1")
    }
}
```

---

This will print

---

> success
>
> 1
>
> a name
>
> name@email.com
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg
>
> anyTokenString

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for that explenation. But it brings up another question, how should I be able to get the values if in another viewcontroller since I have no idea what is the user's id? Otherwise, it works perfectly. I understand perfectly the point, why the id is necessary in the userDefaults's key. But how should I be aware of the user's id globally? I also wanted to mention that I have full privileges over the API, so I can change keys as necessary.

Comment: If you don't need multiple users just use a single key and create an initializer without any parameters

Comment: Ohh, okay. Yep, awesome explenation.